# what is the requirements for npm start to run?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package.json

I can not run `npm start` in my project, this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "babek",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  }
}
```

The terminal says:  `Failed at the babek@1.0.0 start script.`

The project still contains few very basic files. so what can be wrong here, what are the requirements for `npm start` to start the server??

Answer (score 2):

You need to include that under scripts:

```
     "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start"
      }
```